# Permission denied to run git in mounted directories

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, git, 18.04

So I freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. At installation I mounted `C:` and `D:` at `home/drives/C` - `home/drives/D`. I want to keep my working files in `D` therefore I am using git there, but every time I try running `git status`, `git clone` etc, the terminal wants me to use `sudo`.

Did I mount the volumes correctly? How can I get rid of the mounted volumes permissions?

Comment: As its NTFS, it's probably showing root as the owner of those files. See dupe on how to make your user appear as the owner, after which you don't need to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run as root

You can use this command to run the entire terminal as root

```
sudo  -i
```

or

```
sudo su
```

Enter your password and you can do all commands as root

Comment: Thank you :) I am sorry for the easy question but I am fairly new to the OS. Have a nice day.

Comment: no problem. have a nice day :)